# Bluebird Promises and JSON.parse on an Array

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, promise, bluebird

I want to have access on a JSONARRAY in a JSONOBJECT. But after the Bluebird Promises, i can not JSON.parse on the Entrys of the "arrayOfResults". If i would do this, the code is in a deadlock. The database is redis. Please help :)

UPDATE: the code after that part caused the deadlock, sorry :(

```js
var JSONOBJECT = {
 "A":DATA, 
 JSONARRAY :[{A:x}, {B:C}]
};

db.set(SOMEID, JSON.stringify(JSONOBJECT));



function somefunction(ArrayOfIDS){
  var promises = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < ArrayOfIDS.length; i++) {
   promises.push(db.getAsync(ArrayOfIDS[i]));
         }
  return Promise.all(promises).then(function(arrayOfResults) {
   for (i = 0; i < arrayOfResults.length; i++) {
    //THIS IS NOT WORKING, but i need to parse it back to JsonObject
    //var JSONOBJECT = JSON.parse(arrayOfResults[i]);
                
                //The JSONOBJECT below only contains the string of the JSONOBJECT
    var JSONOBJECT = arrayOfResults[i];
                //So this line below is not working
                                var JSONARRAY = JSONOBJECT.JSONARRAY;
   }
   //SOME MORE CODE
   return SOMETHING;
  });
};
```

Comment: can you show us, what arrayOfResults contains?

Comment: It contains the value of JSON.stringify(JSONOBJECT), so only the string of a JSONOBJECT in each Entry of arrayOFResults :(

Comment: @Arzan0 Im pretty sure that you don't have a deadlock as there are no cycles in the dependency graph here. Most probably the results are not proper json strings, thus JSON.parse fails and the promise rejects. Try handling promise rejections, at least log them to console.

Comment: What exactly does "*THIS IS NOT WORKING*" refer to? What error do you get if you simply parse the JSON string? What's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

arrayOfResults contains promise results, not values, so you cant apply sync methods like JSON.parse

try this function

```
function somefunction(ArrayOfIDS) {
    return Promise.map(ArrayOfIDS, function(ID, index){
        return Promise.resolve()
            .then(function(){
                return db.getAsync(ID);
            })
            .then(function(JSONOBJECT) {
                return {
                    obj: JSON.parse(JSONOBJECT),
                    index: index
                }
            })
    })
    .then(function(ARRAYOFJSONOBJECTS){
        return SOMETHING;
    });
}
```

Comment: How can i get the last return of "somefunction" ?

Comment: Still a deadlock if i use JSON.parse. The function db.getAsync(ID) returns the String of a JSONOBJECT.

Comment: @Arzan0 can you post actual code what are you doing? I dont understand

Comment: It was a deadlock in the code after that part, sorry :(